# Best way for CSV reading in Apache Utils

Tags: java

What is the best option to go for CSV reading? I know that there is a way using super-csv API, java-csv API. But my boss asked me to one the API which is only provided by the Apache organization. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You mean like the first link on [Google: apache csv](http://www.google.com/search?q=apache+csv)?

Comment: A simple search turned up this:  http://commons.apache.org/csv/ 
If that's  still current, there isn't YET an Apache CSV module officially available, but a beta is available for download from a link on that page.

Comment: do you even need a library ? reading a csv file is pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

You said in your original question:

> only provided by the Apache organization

The [Apache Commons CSV Project](http://commons.apache.org/csv/) is currently in the [Commons Sandbox](http://commons.apache.org/sandbox/).

From the Commons CSV Page:

> There are currently no official downloads, and will not be until CSV moves out of the Sandbox, but a nightly build is available from http://people.apache.org/builds/commons/nightly/commons-csv/

One caution I would mention is that the latest nightly build I found here was 30-Jul-2007.

99% of the time I would advocate not re-inventing the wheel.  For example, using Apache Commons Lang StringUtils, instead of rolling your own String Utility classes to check for blank or empty Strings.

However, due to the fact that:

- Apache Commons CSV is in the Sandbox
- Could not find any nightly builds more recent than July 2007
- Relative ease of writing your own CSV parser

This is a scenario where I would recommend writing your own.

If you just need to read and parse a Comma-separated Values file, you should be able to accomplish this without too much code or difficulty using core Java IO and Util classes.

You should just be able to wrap a `java.io.FileReader` in a `java.io.BufferedReader`, read line by line.

For each line, use a `java.util.StringTokenizer` to split on the commas.

This is the logic you would need, obviously you would need to take care of closing readers, Exception Handling, etc.